# Un «quasi» superfluo in un testo di Pirandello?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel capitolo 3 di *Il fu Mattia Pascal* di Pirandello c'è la frase:

> *La sua morte quasi improvvisa fu la nostra rovina*.

Si dice della morte del padre di Mattia Pascal. Il significato della frase è molto chiaro: suo padre ha guadagnato una ricchezza che sua madre non ha potuto conservare. Ma ho la domanda: perché la parola *quasi* è necessaria? Che vuole dire qui? Mi pare di capire il significato generale di *quasi*: vuole dire sempre un'approssimazione di qualche sorta. Ma di che approssimazione si dovrebbe trattare qui? Il padre è morto in tre giorni per una malattia. Per me, questa morte è improvvisa senz'alcuna approssimazione. Dunque che vuole dire *quasi* qui? Non posso credere che Pirandello usi delle parole superflue che non vogliono dire niente. Grazie!

Comment: Una morte improvvisa non è preceduta da alcun segnale. Tre giorni di malattia…

Comment: Penso che il significato sia che la malattia che ha causato la morte del padre ha avuto un andamento molto rapido. In questo senso, la morte non è stata improvvisa, ma *quasi improvvisa*.

Comment: Forse… Eppure è probabile che i parenti non hanno ricevuto la notizia della sua malattia fino all'ora della sua morte… Si dice che è morto a Corsica, lontano dalla famiglia.

Comment: Come dice @egreg, una morte è improvvisa se uno cammina per strada, si accascia al suolo e non si rialza più. Tre giorni fanno una bella differenza.

Comment: Non mi sembra una domanda sulla lingua italiana, tutto sommato. A parte che una morte sopravvenuta in tre giorni non è del tutto improvvisa, se anche fosse una scelta ironica o altro, non concerne comunque il significato letterale della parola “quasi”.

Comment: @DaG vuoi dire che è una domanda sulla parola "improvvisa"... Per me la notizia che la morte sopravvenuta in tre giorni non è improvvisa è almeno interessante. Grazie.

Comment: @DaG questo dipende dalla lingua, come sempre. Il metodo di ricerca sarebbe studiare un corpo di testi italiani per le occorrenze della parola "improvviso", perché questi tinti di significato non sono cacciati nei dizionari, abitualmente. Ma per me la confirmazione dei madrelingua va bene lo stesso. Grazie.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Il senso fondamentale di improvviso, anche senza cercare a fondo nei corpora, è “Di cosa che giunge imprevista, inaspettata, senza alcun preannuncio” ([Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/improvviso1)). Tre giorni, da qualunque punto di vista, sono un tempo bello lungo (per prevedere e preannunciare etc.). “Morte improvvisa” si dice di un incidente, di un infarto fulminante etc., non di una morte per malattia.

Comment: @Evgeniy (Scusa se mi permetto: “tinti di significato” non è molto chiaro; penso che tu intenda “sfumature di significato”. E “cacciato” in un dizionario non si dice; si dice “inserito” o “riportato”.)

Comment: @DaG ho già detto che i parenti probabilmente non hanno ricevuto alcun segno prima della notizia della morte. Telegrafati? Non credo. Potrebbe essere importante. Oppure potrebbe non lo essere. Nella mia lingua, probabilmente lo è. Sono sfumature di significato che non sono citati nei dizionari perché fanno lo spirito della lingua. Scusami, non mi sembra che tu comprenda che cosa difficile la lingua è. :) Intendo, la lingua in generale.

Comment: @Evgeniy. Non importa come siano stati avvertiti i parenti. La morte è un evento in sé: improvviso, lento, doloroso, sereno, quel che sia. Magari poi tu e io lo veniamo a sapere tre anni dopo. Che c'entra? La frase parla chiaramente di “morte quasi improvvisa”, non di comunicazione non tempestiva o altro.

Comment: @Evgeniy. (Grazie, ma mi rendo conto benissimo della difficoltà dei fenomeni linguistici; li studio da decenni. Forse sei tu che non ti rendi conto che alcune tue osservazioni possono suonare offensive.)

Comment: @DaG eppure hai torto quando dici che quel che dici sull'importanza di certe cose non appartiene alla lingua ma invece appartiene alla natura generale di cose ecc. Non voglio offenderti, solo dico quel che so. Okay, let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @DaG If you want to discuss it separately, I am to your services, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119623/discussion-between-dag-and-evgeniy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il *quasi* nel testo di Pirandello non è superfluo. Come ha detto @egreg nel suo commento, una morte *improvvisa* è quella che non è preceduta da nessun segnale che passa far sospettare che la persona stia arrivando a fin di vita.

La morte del padre di Mattia Pascal non è *improvvisa* perché è preceduta da tre giorni di malattia. È invece *quasi improvvisa* nel senso che la malattia che ha causato la morte ha avuto un andamento molto rapido: il processo ha durato soltanto tre giorni.

Answer (score 1):

I commenti alla domanda mi trovano piuttosto d'accordo: tre giorni di malattia non rappresentano una morte improvvisa. Ho letto con piacere Il fu "Mattia Pascal" e non bisogna dimenticare l'umorismo che l'autore usa, a tratti quasi canzonatorio a mio modesto parere. Cioè la morte è di per sé un evento che può sconvolgere una famiglia. Perché la domanda retorica è "sarebbe stato meno problematico per la famiglia che il padre fosse morto immediatamente? Oppure avesse sofferto lungamente per una malattia?". Può essere che l'autore sottolinei con l'umorismo che amo l'ipocrisia di queste affermazioni.